# Python - How to sort a list with another list that contains new indices for 1st list

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

`original_list = ['Atlanta', 'New York', 'Miami', 'Chicago']`

and a second list, that contains the indices that the 1st list should be sorted to:

`index_list = [1, 3, 0, 2]`

The result should be

`new_list = ['New York', 'Chicago', 'Atlanta', 'Miami']`

I tried using the "Key" parameter of Python's "Sorted" function , but can't get it to work. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Something like this: `new_list = [e[1] for e in sorted(zip(index_list, original_list), reverse=True)]`?

Comment: Working with the `key` parameter of `sorted`isn't the best idea: `new_list = list(sorted(original_list, key=lambda e: index_list[original_list.index(e)], reverse=True))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can import numpy, just use it !

```
import numpy as np

oldList = np.array(['Atlanta', 'New York', 'Miami', 'Chicago'])

indexes = [1, 3, 0, 2]
newList = oldList[indexes]
```

Otherwise:

```
newList = [oldList[index] for index in indexes]
```

Comment: That second approach is great.